# Short question about arbitrary epsilon

Tags: real-analysis, logic, quantifiers

Hello all I am just wondering if my thoughts on this are correct.

Suppose we are just talking about some bounded set $$A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$$

we say $w$ is a sup of A iff it is an upper bound of A and $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$ there $\exists$ an $a_{\epsilon} \in A$ such that $$w-\epsilon \lt a_{\epsilon}$$

Then could we also say the same but instead using $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

ie it is the supremum iff it is an upper bound and $\forall \frac{\epsilon}{2} \gt 0$ there $\exists$ an $a_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$ $\in A$ such that $$w-\frac{\epsilon}{2} \lt a_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$$

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to say "for all $\varepsilon / 2 > 0$. Usually you see "for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $a_\varepsilon \in A$ such that $w - \varepsilon/2 < a_\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary this is possible.

Comment: Yes, they seem to be correct to me, since the statement is true for all $\epsilon$

Comment: You say $\forall x$ satisfying a certain condition (say, $x>0$) someting is true. Here $x$ is a "new variable", i.e., just a letter. You don't say $\forall \sin x$ something is true.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: I fully agree with your comment. However, too many times I have seen teachers use sloppy notation like $\forall 1<x<n\ ( \cdots )$. This should of course be gotten rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your thoughts are correct. The supremum (or least upper bound) of a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is defined as a number $w$ such that:

1. $w$ is an upper bound of $A$.
2. For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $a \in A$ such that $w - \epsilon < a$.

The choice of $\epsilon$ or $\epsilon^2$ doesn't change the definition. As long as $\epsilon^2 > 0$, there should exist an $a \in A$ such that $w - \epsilon^2 < a$. This is because the condition is meant to ensure that $w$ is the *least* upper bound, i.e., there are elements of $A$ arbitrarily close to $w$. Whether you use $\epsilon$ or $\epsilon^2$ (or any other positive quantity) doesn't change this fact. So yes, you could also use $\epsilon^2$ in the definition. Good job on your understanding of the concept!